Why client files are not defined when i'm uploading a new file?
The thing is, when I upload a new file, if it doesn't find the file, it should send it to the backend validation. However, I am uploading a new file but it doesn't find it and marks it as undefined.
Screenshot: customerFiles is undefined
console.logs
Code:
async upload(customerFileType: CustomerFileType, event: any) {
    let cft: any = customerFileType;
    cft.loading = true;
    try {
        console.log(this.customerFilesForm);
        let file: File | null = event.target.files.item(0);
        let _extension = this.getExtension(file!.name);
        if (_extension != '.pdf' && _extension != '.png' && _extension != '.jpg' && _extension != '.jpeg') {
            cft.loading = false;
            this._alertService.showErrorAlert('Favor de solo subir archivos PDF e imagenes', null);
        } else {
            const formData = new FormData();
            formData.append('file', file!);
            const fileResponse = await this._fileService.uploadFile(formData);
            console.log(fileResponse);

            if (fileResponse) {
                const fileFound = this.customerFiles.find(a => a.getCustomerFileType?.getIdCustomerFileType == customerFileType.getIdCustomerFileType);
                console.log(fileFound);
                if (fileFound) {
                    this.customerFilesForm.controls.map(affc => {
                        if (affc.value.customerFileType.getIdCustomerFileType == fileFound.getCustomerFileType?.getIdCustomerFileType) {
                            fileFound.setName = fileResponse.name;
                            affc.get('name')?.setValue(fileResponse.name);
                            console.log(affc);
                            this.customerFiles.push(fileResponse.customerFiles);
                        }
                    });
                }
                else if (this.fromTemplate == false) {
                    console.log(this.fromTemplate)
                    const filesFound = this.files.find(a => a.getCustomerFileType?.getIdCustomerFileType == customerFileType.getIdCustomerFileType);
                    filesFound!.setName = fileResponse.name;
                    this.customerFiles.push(filesFound!);
                    this.customerFilesForm.push(this.createFileForm(filesFound!));
                    console.log(this.customerFiles)
                    console.log(this.customerFilesForm)
                }
                else {
                    let _fileUploaded = new CustomerFile();
                    _fileUploaded.setName = fileResponse.name;
                    _fileUploaded.setCustomer = this.customer && this.customer.getIdCustomer ? this.customer : undefined;
                    _fileUploaded.setStatus = CustomerFile.ENABLE;
                    _fileUploaded.setCustomerFileType = customerFileType;
                    this.customerFiles.push(_fileUploaded);
                    this.customerFilesForm.push(this.createFileForm(_fileUploaded));
                }
                console.log(this.customerFilesForm);
                this.customerFilesFormEmitter.emit(this.customerFilesForm);
                cft.loading = false;
            }
        }
    } catch (error: any) {
        cft.loading = false;
        this._alertService.showErrorAlert(error, null);
    }
}


HI, welcome to stackoverfloe. Could you please show how you have defined the variable 'this.customerFiles'
